# Django-dynamic-scraper get 301 error when downloading image

Tags: django, web-scraping, django-dynamic-scraper

I am trying to configure scraping data using django-dynamic-scraper. Everything have been working fine until i desided to add image scraping.
I have done everything like in this docs [part Scrapy images/screenshots](https://github.com/holgerd77/django-dynamic-scraper/blob/master/docs/advanced_topics.rst#configurationd)

But when i run scraper i get something like this (301 error while downloading file)[image]

I will be grateful for any advice.

Comment: You know what 301 errors mean, right? http://devdocs.io/http/rfc7231#section-6.4.2 Files you're trying to access on commons do not exist. They're thumbnails, many of which aren't permanent, because they were generated, probably on the fly and cached for a while. Try scraping a different website or url for images that exist. I manually entered some of the requests in the screenshot, and they were reported missing. Dead ends!

Comment: Ok the problem was that i added http pre_url while wikinews uses https.